# Promotion Effectiveness lacking a control group

Tags: time-series

I want to measure the effectiveness of a promotion but I'm lacking a true control group. The data I have consists of a user base that can opt into signing up for a promotion (every user has access to the promotion). Currently, I am using users who opted into the promotion as my test group and those that did not as my control. My thought was using Google's Causal Impact to determine the counterfactual, but I am worried that I'm not capturing the underlying relationship between the two groups of users. Just wanted to see if my thought process is correct, or should I be using a different technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what you are actually measuring as the result of the promotion, but let's say it is something like sales.

Your data is currently not really useful to measure the causal effect of a promotion on sales. It is very likely that you have hidden [confounders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding) in your scenario: E.g., it could be that only very engaged users opted into the promotion and those would have generated higher sales anyway. The confounder here would be the property of the user to be engaged or not. Then you would obtain a correlation between promotion and increased sales without an actual effect of promotion.

One standard way of circumventing those problems is by doing proper randomization, i.e. don't let the users decide about the promotion but assign the promotion yourself, and do so *really randomly*.

[Google's CausalImpact](http://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html) requires you to train a model for sales before the intervention, i.e. *all* participants are *without* the promotion, then to intervene on *all* participants, i.e. give *all* of them the promotion, and then compare the predictions of sales given by the above model (i.e. how the sales would have continued without promotion) with the actual sales after the promotion. Again, this doesn't seem to fit your current data.

Comment: Thanks! I am measuring total revenue. Unfortunately, there's a technical limitation which stops a proper randomization. I do however have data prior to the promotion for both groups (opt-ins and opt-outs) and post the data. I ran an example where I used the opt-out group as my independent variable/control group and the opt-in as dependent. However, based on what you have said, should I be forecasting both groups?

Comment: You can use CausalImpact on the opt-ins. This algorithm will compare the *predicted* behavior of the opt-ins (how the model thinks the opt-ins' revenue would continue without the promotion) with the actual revenue of the opt-ins after the promotion. The data for the opt-outs will not be useful here.

Comment: Thank you! Just curious since it's my first time using CausalImpact, don't you need an independent variable to run it with?

Comment: Yes, you need independent variables. Are you saying you are considering using the total revenue of the opt-outs as the independent variables? If (1) you can indeed predict reasonably well the pre-intervention revenue of the opt-ins from the pre-intervention revenue of the opt-outs and (2) you are sure that the revenue of the opt-outs will not be affected by the very act of "opting-out" of the promotion, this might work.